# ERROR: extension "pgoutput" is not available while trying to use it with airbyte to replicate the data from PostgreSQL in real-time using CDC

Tags: postgresql, cdc, wal, airbyte

I am planning to use [airbyte](https://airbyte.com/) to replicate data from my PostgreSQL database to Elasticsearch in real-time using CDC. According to the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_integration/2019-12/html/change_data_capture_user_guide/debezium-connector-for-postgresql)

[image]

```
The pgoutput plug-in is always present, meaning that no additional libraries must be installed, 
and the connector will interpret the raw replication event stream into change events directly.
```

So, when I tried to run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "pgoutput";`

It is showing this error.

```
SQL Error [0A000]: ERROR: extension "pgoutput" is not available
  Detail: Could not open extension control file "/usr/local/share/postgresql/extension/pgoutput.control": No such file or directory.
  Hint: The extension must first be installed on the system where PostgreSQL is running.
```

How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance for detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

`pgoutput` is not an extension, it is "always present". Just use it in a replication slot, for example:

```
SELECT pg_create_logical_replication_slot('slot_name', 'pgoutput');
```